# Fantasy YA book with a female orphaned protagonist who finds a scroll that enables her to fly and escape her town surrounded by a forest

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book before 2018 and it was already in paperback.

The plot starts with the main character, a girl, waking up in a tree to find a scroll that enables her to fly. She is an orphan, but still has her younger brother, who in the story gets taken to live in the mayor's house, whom I recall is a bad character. In this world, the village is surrounded by a forest with monsters and nobody can escape. Everyone gets allocated what work they will do and the protagonist has to work in a factory, but when she goes back one night to see what is happening, things go wrong as she discovers a plot. She realises that everyone is being trapped and at the end manages to escape by flying over the edge of the forest with her male best friend.

It should be in a series as it definitely didn't have a final ending.